# vscode is not giving valid intellice for pyspark code

Tags: visual-studio-code, pyspark

I am using vscode to develop pyspark, and I expect it to give me pyspark functions when I am writing code, for example in the below drop-down. I am getting some python functions when I say "df.", but it doesn't provide me with pyspark-specific functions. How to get this in drop-down?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to seetings.json in vscode

```
"python.languageServer": "JediLSP",
```